# addig char in select statement

Tags: oracle

I want to add char in Select statement.

Ex:

```
SELECT '.' + OUTTRUNK as NUMBER
```

Expected Result:

```
.348977834
.456935534
.090922834
.234999734
```

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the more SQL-ish:

```
SELECT '.' || OUTTRUNK as NUMBER
```

but keep in mind that, if `OUTRUNK` is a *numeric* rather than string type, you'll probably find that `090922834` will actually be `90922834` and will render as `.90922834`, not what you want.

If that's the case, you're probably looking for something more like:

```
SELECT OUTTRUNK / 1000000000 as NUMBER
```

(check the number of zeros there, I tried to get it right but testing is rightly your concern).